# Uppercase All String According to Locale - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslocale

I'm trying to uppercase all string according to 'Locale' but it is not working.

```
var text = "istanbul, izmir"

println(text.uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale()))
```

In Turkish language the uppercase for i is İ not I. My Result is ISTANBUL, IZMIR but It should returns İSTANBUL, İZMİR.

Please where would be my issue?

Comment: In Turkish language the capital of i is İ not I so I should get İSTANBUL @EICaptain

Comment: @EICaptain it is returning ISTANBUL

Comment: What is your current locale? `print(text.uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "tr")))` gives the expected output "İSTANBUL, İZMİR". – Please show the output of `print(NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier)`.

Comment: @MartinR this is working fine. My iPhone is set to English and this method converted the text as I want.

Comment: @MartinR my issue is my locale is en_US but now with you code(localeIdentifier) is changing it. Add your answer please so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`NSLocale.currentLocale()` is the locale which was selected in the
Settings of the device. If that is "en_US" then

```
text.uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
```

will use the english language rules and the result is "ISTANBUL, IZMIR".

You can either select the turkish language in the device settings, or
specify the turkish locale explicitly:

```
let text = "istanbul, izmir"
text.uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "tr"))
// İSTANBUL, İZMİR
```

**Swift 3:**

```
text.uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr"))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the current locale, you can use:

```
text.localizedUppercaseString
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3.x, 4.x, 5.0**
regardless of ISO standards, Apple using "tr" for Turkish language without country shortcode. you must explicitly set an identifier (if you don't care device settings from 'Local.current')

```
"istanbul, izmir, ateştuğla".uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr"))

// Output is:
// "İSTANBUL, İZMİR, ATEŞTUĞLA"
```

to see all available identifiers i suggest to print them all, to your debugging console by:

```
po Locale.availableIdentifiers
```

..
Here is an example output from LLDB of XCode.10.2 by swift5:

```
(lldb) po Locale.availableIdentifiers
▿ 797 elements
  - 0 : "eu"
  - 1 : "hr_BA"
  - 2 : "en_CM"
  - 3 : "en_BI"
  - 4 : "rw_RW"
  - 5 : "ast"
  - 6 : "en_SZ"
  - 7 : "he_IL"
  - 8 : "ar"
  - 9 : "uz_Arab"
  - 10 : "en_PN"
  - 11 : "as"
  - 12 : "en_NF"
  - 13 : "ks_IN"
  - 14 : "es_KY"
  - 15 : "rwk_TZ"
  - 16 : "zh_Hant_TW"
  - 17 : "en_CN"
  - 18 : "gsw_LI"
  - 19 : "ta_IN"
  - 20 : "th_TH"
  - 21 : "es_EA"
  - 22 : "fr_GF"
  - 23 : "ar_001"
  - 24 : "en_RW"
  - 25 : "tr_TR"
  - 26 : "de_CH"
  - 27 : "ee_TG"
  - 28 : "en_NG"
  - 29 : "fr_TG"
  - 30 : "az"
  - 31 : "fr_SC"
  - 32 : "es_HN"
  - 33 : "en_AG"
  - 34 : "ccp_IN"
  - 35 : "ru_KZ"
  - 36 : "gsw"
  - 37 : "dyo"
  - 38 : "so_ET"
  - 39 : "zh_Hant_MO"
  - 40 : "de_BE"
  - 41 : "nus_SS"
  - 42 : "km_KH"
  - 43 : "my_MM"
  - 44 : "mgh_MZ"
  - 45 : "ee_GH"
  - 46 : "es_EC"
  - 47 : "kw_GB"
  - 48 : "rm_CH"
  - 49 : "en_ME"
  - 50 : "nyn"
  - 51 : "mk_MK"
  - 52 : "bs_Cyrl_BA"
  - 53 : "ar_MR"
  - 54 : "es_GL"
  - 55 : "en_BM"
  - 56 : "ms_Arab"
  - 57 : "en_AI"
  - 58 : "gl_ES"
  - 59 : "en_PR"
  - 60 : "ff_CM"
  - 61 : "ne_IN"
  - 62 : "or_IN"
  - 63 : "khq_ML"
  - 64 : "en_MG"
  - 65 : "pt_TL"
  - 66 : "en_LC"
  - 67 : "iu_CA"
  - 68 : "ta_SG"
  - 69 : "jmc_TZ"
  - 70 : "om_ET"
  - 71 : "lv_LV"
  - 72 : "es_US"
  - 73 : "en_PT"
  - 74 : "vai_Latn_LR"
  - 75 : "en_NL"
  - 76 : "to_TO"
  - 77 : "cgg_UG"
  - 78 : "en_MH"
  - 79 : "ta"
  - 80 : "zu_ZA"
  - 81 : "shi_Latn_MA"
  - 82 : "es_FK"
  - 83 : "ar_KM"
  - 84 : "en_AL"
  - 85 : "brx_IN"
  - 86 : "te"
  - 87 : "chr_US"
  - 88 : "yo_BJ"
  - 89 : "fr_VU"
  - 90 : "pa"
  - 91 : "tg"
  - 92 : "kea"
  - 93 : "ksh_DE"
  - 94 : "sw_CD"
  - 95 : "te_IN"
  - 96 : "fr_RE"
  - 97 : "th"
  - 98 : "ur_IN"
  - 99 : "yo_NG"
  - 100 : "ti"
  - 101 : "es_HT"
  - 102 : "es_GP"
  - 103 : "guz_KE"
  - 104 : "tk"
  - 105 : "kl_GL"
  - 106 : "ksf_CM"
  - 107 : "mua_CM"
  - 108 : "lag_TZ"
  - 109 : "lb"
  - 110 : "fr_TN"
  - 111 : "es_PA"
  - 112 : "pl_PL"
  - 113 : "to"
  - 114 : "hi_IN"
  - 115 : "dje_NE"
  - 116 : "es_GQ"
  - 117 : "en_BR"
  - 118 : "kok_IN"
  - 119 : "pl"
  - 120 : "fr_GN"
  - 121 : "bem"
  - 122 : "ha"
  - 123 : "ckb"
  - 124 : "es_CA"
  - 125 : "lg"
  - 126 : "tr"
  - 127 : "en_PW"
  - 128 : "tt"
  - 129 : "en_NO"
  - 130 : "nyn_UG"
  - 131 : "sr_Latn_RS"
  - 132 : "gsw_FR"
  - 133 : "pa_Guru"
  - 134 : "he"
  - 135 : "qu_BO"
  - 136 : "ps_AF"
  - 137 : "lu_CD"
  - 138 : "mgo_CM"
  - 139 : "sn_ZW"
  - 140 : "en_BS"
  - 141 : "da"
  - 142 : "ps"
  - 143 : "ln"
  - 144 : "pt"
  - 145 : "hi"
  - 146 : "lo"
  - 147 : "ebu"
  - 148 : "de"
  - 149 : "gu_IN"
  - 150 : "wo_SN"
  - 151 : "seh"
  - 152 : "en_CX"
  - 153 : "en_ZM"
  - 154 : "fr_HT"
  - 155 : "fr_GP"
  - 156 : "pt_GQ"
  - 157 : "lt"
  - 158 : "lu"
  - 159 : "es_TT"
  - 160 : "ln_CD"
  - 161 : "vai_Latn"
  - 162 : "el_GR"
  - 163 : "lv"
  - 164 : "en_KE"
  - 165 : "sbp"
  - 166 : "hr"
  - 167 : "en_CY"
  - 168 : "es_GT"
  - 169 : "twq_NE"
  - 170 : "zh_Hant_HK"
  - 171 : "kln_KE"
  - 172 : "fr_GQ"
  - 173 : "chr"
  - 174 : "hu"
  - 175 : "es_UY"
  - 176 : "fr_CA"
  - 177 : "ms_BN"
  - 178 : "en_NR"
  - 179 : "mer"
  - 180 : "shi"
  - 181 : "es_PE"
  - 182 : "fr_SN"
  - 183 : "bez"
  - 184 : "sw_TZ"
  - 185 : "wae_CH"
  - 186 : "kkj"
  - 187 : "hy"
  - 188 : "dz_BT"
  - 189 : "en_CZ"
  - 190 : "teo_KE"
  - 191 : "teo"
  - 192 : "en_AR"
  - 193 : "ar_JO"
  - 194 : "yue_Hans_CN"
  - 195 : "mer_KE"
  - 196 : "khq"
  - 197 : "ln_CF"
  - 198 : "nn_NO"
  - 199 : "es_SR"
  - 200 : "en_MO"
  - 201 : "ar_TD"
  - 202 : "dz"
  - 203 : "ses"
  - 204 : "en_BW"
  - 205 : "en_AS"
  - 206 : "ar_IL"
  - 207 : "es_BB"
  - 208 : "bo_CN"
  - 209 : "nnh"
  - 210 : "teo_UG"
  - 211 : "hy_AM"
  - 212 : "ln_CG"
  - 213 : "sr_Latn_BA"
  - 214 : "en_MP"
  - 215 : "ksb_TZ"
  - 216 : "ar_SA"
  - 217 : "smn_FI"
  - 218 : "ar_LY"
  - 219 : "en_AT"
  - 220 : "so_KE"
  - 221 : "fr_CD"
  - 222 : "af_NA"
  - 223 : "en_NU"
  - 224 : "es_PH"
  - 225 : "en_KI"
  - 226 : "en_JE"
  - 227 : "lkt"
  - 228 : "en_AU"
  - 229 : "fa_IR"
  - 230 : "pt_FR"
  - 231 : "uz_Latn_UZ"
  - 232 : "zh_Hans_CN"
  - 233 : "ewo_CM"
  - 234 : "fr_PF"
  - 235 : "ca_IT"
  - 236 : "es_GY"
  - 237 : "en_BZ"
  - 238 : "ar_KW"
  - 239 : "pt_GW"
  - 240 : "fr_FR"
  - 241 : "am_ET"
  - 242 : "en_VC"
  - 243 : "es_DM"
  - 244 : "fr_DJ"
  - 245 : "fr_CF"
  - 246 : "es_SV"
  - 247 : "en_MS"
  - 248 : "pt_ST"
  - 249 : "ar_SD"
  - 250 : "luy_KE"
  - 251 : "gd_GB"
  - 252 : "de_LI"
  - 253 : "it_VA"
  - 254 : "fr_CG"
  - 255 : "pt_CH"
  - 256 : "ckb_IQ"
  - 257 : "zh_Hans_SG"
  - 258 : "en_MT"
  - 259 : "ha_NE"
  - 260 : "en_ID"
  - 261 : "ewo"
  - 262 : "af_ZA"
  - 263 : "os_GE"
  - 264 : "om_KE"
  - 265 : "nl_SR"
  - 266 : "es_ES"
  - 267 : "es_DO"
  - 268 : "ar_IQ"
  - 269 : "fr_CH"
  - 270 : "nnh_CM"
  - 271 : "es_SX"
  - 272 : "es_419"
  - 273 : "en_MU"
  - 274 : "en_US_POSIX"
  - 275 : "yav_CM"
  - 276 : "luo_KE"
  - 277 : "dua_CM"
  - 278 : "et_EE"
  - 279 : "en_IE"
  - 280 : "ak_GH"
  - 281 : "rwk"
  - 282 : "es_CL"
  - 283 : "kea_CV"
  - 284 : "fr_CI"
  - 285 : "ckb_IR"
  - 286 : "fr_BE"
  - 287 : "se"
  - 288 : "en_NZ"
  - 289 : "en_MV"
  - 290 : "en_LR"
  - 291 : "es_PM"
  - 292 : "en_KN"
  - 293 : "nb_SJ"
  - 294 : "ha_NG"
  - 295 : "sg"
  - 296 : "sr_Cyrl_RS"
  - 297 : "ru_RU"
  - 298 : "en_ZW"
  - 299 : "sv_AX"
  - 300 : "ga_IE"
  - 301 : "si"
  - 302 : "wo"
  - 303 : "en_VG"
  - 304 : "ff_MR"
  - 305 : "ky_KG"
  - 306 : "agq_CM"
  - 307 : "mzn"
  - 308 : "fr_BF"
  - 309 : "naq_NA"
  - 310 : "mr_IN"
  - 311 : "en_MW"
  - 312 : "de_AT"
  - 313 : "az_Latn"
  - 314 : "en_LS"
  - 315 : "ka"
  - 316 : "sk"
  - 317 : "sl"
  - 318 : "sn"
  - 319 : "sr_Latn_ME"
  - 320 : "fr_NC"
  - 321 : "so"
  - 322 : "is_IS"
  - 323 : "twq"
  - 324 : "ig_NG"
  - 325 : "sq"
  - 326 : "fo_FO"
  - 327 : "sr"
  - 328 : "tzm"
  - 329 : "ga"
  - 330 : "om"
  - 331 : "en_LT"
  - 332 : "bas_CM"
  - 333 : "se_NO"
  - 334 : "ki"
  - 335 : "nl_BE"
  - 336 : "ar_QA"
  - 337 : "gd"
  - 338 : "sv"
  - 339 : "kk"
  - 340 : "rn_BI"
  - 341 : "es_CO"
  - 342 : "az_Latn_AZ"
  - 343 : "kl"
  - 344 : "or"
  - 345 : "es_AG"
  - 346 : "ca"
  - 347 : "en_VI"
  - 348 : "km"
  - 349 : "os"
  - 350 : "sw"
  - 351 : "en_MY"
  - 352 : "kn"
  - 353 : "en_LU"
  - 354 : "fr_SY"
  - 355 : "ar_TN"
  - 356 : "en_JM"
  - 357 : "fr_PM"
  - 358 : "ko"
  - 359 : "fr_NE"
  - 360 : "ce"
  - 361 : "fr_MA"
  - 362 : "gl"
  - 363 : "ru_MD"
  - 364 : "es_BL"
  - 365 : "saq_KE"
  - 366 : "ks"
  - 367 : "fr_CM"
  - 368 : "lb_LU"
  - 369 : "gv_IM"
  - 370 : "fr_BI"
  - 371 : "en_LV"
  - 372 : "en_KR"
  - 373 : "es_NI"
  - 374 : "en_GB"
  - 375 : "kw"
  - 376 : "nl_SX"
  - 377 : "dav_KE"
  - 378 : "tr_CY"
  - 379 : "ky"
  - 380 : "en_UG"
  - 381 : "es_BM"
  - 382 : "en_TC"
  - 383 : "es_AI"
  - 384 : "ar_EG"
  - 385 : "fr_BJ"
  - 386 : "gu"
  - 387 : "es_PR"
  - 388 : "fr_RW"
  - 389 : "gv"
  - 390 : "lrc_IQ"
  - 391 : "sr_Cyrl_BA"
  - 392 : "es_MF"
  - 393 : "fr_MC"
  - 394 : "cs"
  - 395 : "bez_TZ"
  - 396 : "es_CR"
  - 397 : "asa_TZ"
  - 398 : "ar_EH"
  - 399 : "fo_DK"
  - 400 : "ms_Arab_BN"
  - 401 : "ccp"
  - 402 : "en_JP"
  - 403 : "sbp_TZ"
  - 404 : "en_IL"
  - 405 : "lt_LT"
  - 406 : "mfe"
  - 407 : "en_GD"
  - 408 : "es_LC"
  - 409 : "cy"
  - 410 : "ug_CN"
  - 411 : "ca_FR"
  - 412 : "es_BO"
  - 413 : "en_SA"
  - 414 : "fr_BL"
  - 415 : "bn_IN"
  - 416 : "uz_Cyrl_UZ"
  - 417 : "lrc_IR"
  - 418 : "az_Cyrl"
  - 419 : "en_IM"
  - 420 : "sw_KE"
  - 421 : "en_SB"
  - 422 : "pa_Arab"
  - 423 : "ur_PK"
  - 424 : "haw_US"
  - 425 : "ar_SO"
  - 426 : "en_IN"
  - 427 : "fil"
  - 428 : "fr_MF"
  - 429 : "en_WS"
  - 430 : "es_CU"
  - 431 : "es_BQ"
  - 432 : "ja_JP"
  - 433 : "fy_NL"
  - 434 : "en_SC"
  - 435 : "yue_Hant_HK"
  - 436 : "en_IO"
  - 437 : "pt_PT"
  - 438 : "en_HK"
  - 439 : "en_GG"
  - 440 : "fr_MG"
  - 441 : "de_LU"
  - 442 : "tzm_MA"
  - 443 : "es_BR"
  - 444 : "en_TH"
  - 445 : "en_SD"
  - 446 : "nds_DE"
  - 447 : "shi_Tfng"
  - 448 : "ln_AO"
  - 449 : "as_IN"
  - 450 : "en_GH"
  - 451 : "ms_MY"
  - 452 : "ro_RO"
  - 453 : "jgo_CM"
  - 454 : "es_CW"
  - 455 : "dua"
  - 456 : "en_UM"
  - 457 : "es_BS"
  - 458 : "en_SE"
  - 459 : "kn_IN"
  - 460 : "en_KY"
  - 461 : "vun_TZ"
  - 462 : "kln"
  - 463 : "lrc"
  - 464 : "en_GI"
  - 465 : "ca_ES"
  - 466 : "rof"
  - 467 : "pt_CV"
  - 468 : "kok"
  - 469 : "pt_BR"
  - 470 : "ar_DJ"
  - 471 : "yi_001"
  - 472 : "fi_FI"
  - 473 : "zh"
  - 474 : "es_PY"
  - 475 : "ar_SS"
  - 476 : "mua"
  - 477 : "sr_Cyrl_ME"
  - 478 : "vai_Vaii_LR"
  - 479 : "en_001"
  - 480 : "nl_NL"
  - 481 : "en_TK"
  - 482 : "fr_DZ"
  - 483 : "en_SG"
  - 484 : "ca_AD"
  - 485 : "si_LK"
  - 486 : "sv_SE"
  - 487 : "pt_AO"
  - 488 : "vi"
  - 489 : "xog_UG"
  - 490 : "xog"
  - 491 : "en_IS"
  - 492 : "nb"
  - 493 : "seh_MZ"
  - 494 : "es_AR"
  - 495 : "sk_SK"
  - 496 : "en_SH"
  - 497 : "ti_ER"
  - 498 : "nd"
  - 499 : "az_Cyrl_AZ"
  - 500 : "zu"
  - 501 : "ne"
  - 502 : "nd_ZW"
  - 503 : "el_CY"
  - 504 : "en_IT"
  - 505 : "nl_BQ"
  - 506 : "da_GL"
  - 507 : "ja"
  - 508 : "rm"
  - 509 : "fr_ML"
  - 510 : "rn"
  - 511 : "en_VU"
  - 512 : "rof_TZ"
  - 513 : "ro"
  - 514 : "ebu_KE"
  - 515 : "ru_KG"
  - 516 : "en_SI"
  - 517 : "sg_CF"
  - 518 : "mfe_MU"
  - 519 : "nl"
  - 520 : "brx"
  - 521 : "bs_Latn"
  - 522 : "fa"
  - 523 : "zgh_MA"
  - 524 : "en_GM"
  - 525 : "shi_Latn"
  - 526 : "en_FI"
  - 527 : "nn"
  - 528 : "en_EE"
  - 529 : "ru"
  - 530 : "yue"
  - 531 : "kam_KE"
  - 532 : "fur"
  - 533 : "vai_Vaii"
  - 534 : "ar_ER"
  - 535 : "rw"
  - 536 : "ti_ET"
  - 537 : "ff"
  - 538 : "luo"
  - 539 : "fa_AF"
  - 540 : "nl_CW"
  - 541 : "es_MQ"
  - 542 : "en_HR"
  - 543 : "en_FJ"
  - 544 : "fi"
  - 545 : "pt_MO"
  - 546 : "be"
  - 547 : "en_US"
  - 548 : "en_TO"
  - 549 : "en_SK"
  - 550 : "bg"
  - 551 : "ru_BY"
  - 552 : "it_IT"
  - 553 : "ml_IN"
  - 554 : "gsw_CH"
  - 555 : "qu_EC"
  - 556 : "fo"
  - 557 : "sv_FI"
  - 558 : "en_FK"
  - 559 : "nus"
  - 560 : "ta_LK"
  - 561 : "vun"
  - 562 : "sr_Latn"
  - 563 : "es_BZ"
  - 564 : "fr"
  - 565 : "en_SL"
  - 566 : "bm"
  - 567 : "es_VC"
  - 568 : "ar_BH"
  - 569 : "guz"
  - 570 : "bn"
  - 571 : "bo"
  - 572 : "ar_SY"
  - 573 : "es_MS"
  - 574 : "lo_LA"
  - 575 : "ne_NP"
  - 576 : "uz_Latn"
  - 577 : "be_BY"
  - 578 : "es_IC"
  - 579 : "sr_Latn_XK"
  - 580 : "ar_MA"
  - 581 : "pa_Guru_IN"
  - 582 : "br"
  - 583 : "luy"
  - 584 : "kde_TZ"
  - 585 : "es_AW"
  - 586 : "bs"
  - 587 : "fy"
  - 588 : "fur_IT"
  - 589 : "hu_HU"
  - 590 : "ar_AE"
  - 591 : "en_HU"
  - 592 : "sah_RU"
  - 593 : "zh_Hans"
  - 594 : "en_FM"
  - 595 : "fr_MQ"
  - 596 : "ko_KP"
  - 597 : "en_150"
  - 598 : "en_DE"
  - 599 : "ce_RU"
  - 600 : "en_CA"
  - 601 : "hsb_DE"
  - 602 : "sq_AL"
  - 603 : "en_TR"
  - 604 : "ro_MD"
  - 605 : "es_VE"
  - 606 : "tg_TJ"
  - 607 : "fr_WF"
  - 608 : "mt_MT"
  - 609 : "kab"
  - 610 : "nmg_CM"
  - 611 : "ms_SG"
  - 612 : "en_GR"
  - 613 : "ru_UA"
  - 614 : "fr_MR"
  - 615 : "zh_Hans_MO"
  - 616 : "de_IT"
  - 617 : "ccp_BD"
  - 618 : "ff_GN"
  - 619 : "bs_Cyrl"
  - 620 : "tt_RU"
  - 621 : "nds_NL"
  - 622 : "es_KN"
  - 623 : "sw_UG"
  - 624 : "yue_Hans"
  - 625 : "ko_KR"
  - 626 : "en_DG"
  - 627 : "bo_IN"
  - 628 : "en_CC"
  - 629 : "shi_Tfng_MA"
  - 630 : "lag"
  - 631 : "it_SM"
  - 632 : "os_RU"
  - 633 : "en_TT"
  - 634 : "ms_Arab_MY"
  - 635 : "sq_MK"
  - 636 : "es_VG"
  - 637 : "bem_ZM"
  - 638 : "kde"
  - 639 : "ar_OM"
  - 640 : "kk_KZ"
  - 641 : "cgg"
  - 642 : "bas"
  - 643 : "kam"
  - 644 : "wae"
  - 645 : "es_MX"
  - 646 : "sah"
  - 647 : "zh_Hant"
  - 648 : "en_GU"
  - 649 : "fr_MU"
  - 650 : "fr_KM"
  - 651 : "ar_LB"
  - 652 : "en_BA"
  - 653 : "en_TV"
  - 654 : "sr_Cyrl"
  - 655 : "mzn_IR"
  - 656 : "es_VI"
  - 657 : "dje"
  - 658 : "kab_DZ"
  - 659 : "fil_PH"
  - 660 : "se_SE"
  - 661 : "vai"
  - 662 : "hr_HR"
  - 663 : "bs_Latn_BA"
  - 664 : "nl_AW"
  - 665 : "dav"
  - 666 : "so_SO"
  - 667 : "ar_PS"
  - 668 : "en_FR"
  - 669 : "uz_Cyrl"
  - 670 : "ff_SN"
  - 671 : "en_BB"
  - 672 : "ki_KE"
  - 673 : "en_TW"
  - 674 : "naq"
  - 675 : "en_SS"
  - 676 : "mg_MG"
  - 677 : "mas_KE"
  - 678 : "en_RO"
  - 679 : "en_PG"
  - 680 : "mgh"
  - 681 : "dyo_SN"
  - 682 : "mas"
  - 683 : "agq"
  - 684 : "bn_BD"
  - 685 : "haw"
  - 686 : "yi"
  - 687 : "nb_NO"
  - 688 : "da_DK"
  - 689 : "en_DK"
  - 690 : "saq"
  - 691 : "ug"
  - 692 : "cy_GB"
  - 693 : "fr_YT"
  - 694 : "jmc"
  - 695 : "ses_ML"
  - 696 : "en_PH"
  - 697 : "de_DE"
  - 698 : "ar_YE"
  - 699 : "es_TC"
  - 700 : "bm_ML"
  - 701 : "yo"
  - 702 : "lkt_US"
  - 703 : "uz_Arab_AF"
  - 704 : "jgo"
  - 705 : "sl_SI"
  - 706 : "pt_LU"
  - 707 : "uk"
  - 708 : "en_CH"
  - 709 : "asa"
  - 710 : "en_BD"
  - 711 : "lg_UG"
  - 712 : "nds"
  - 713 : "qu_PE"
  - 714 : "mgo"
  - 715 : "id_ID"
  - 716 : "en_NA"
  - 717 : "en_GY"
  - 718 : "zgh"
  - 719 : "pt_MZ"
  - 720 : "fr_LU"
  - 721 : "dsb"
  - 722 : "mas_TZ"
  - 723 : "en_DM"
  - 724 : "ta_MY"
  - 725 : "es_GD"
  - 726 : "en_BE"
  - 727 : "mg"
  - 728 : "ur"
  - 729 : "fr_GA"
  - 730 : "ka_GE"
  - 731 : "nmg"
  - 732 : "en_TZ"
  - 733 : "eu_ES"
  - 734 : "ar_DZ"
  - 735 : "id"
  - 736 : "so_DJ"
  - 737 : "hsb"
  - 738 : "yav"
  - 739 : "mk"
  - 740 : "pa_Arab_PK"
  - 741 : "ml"
  - 742 : "en_ER"
  - 743 : "ig"
  - 744 : "se_FI"
  - 745 : "mn"
  - 746 : "ksb"
  - 747 : "uz"
  - 748 : "vi_VN"
  - 749 : "ii"
  - 750 : "qu"
  - 751 : "en_PK"
  - 752 : "ee"
  - 753 : "ast_ES"
  - 754 : "yue_Hant"
  - 755 : "mr"
  - 756 : "ms"
  - 757 : "en_ES"
  - 758 : "ha_GH"
  - 759 : "it_CH"
  - 760 : "sq_XK"
  - 761 : "mt"
  - 762 : "en_CK"
  - 763 : "br_FR"
  - 764 : "en_BG"
  - 765 : "es_GF"
  - 766 : "tk_TM"
  - 767 : "sr_Cyrl_XK"
  - 768 : "ksf"
  - 769 : "en_SX"
  - 770 : "bg_BG"
  - 771 : "en_PL"
  - 772 : "af"
  - 773 : "el"
  - 774 : "cs_CZ"
  - 775 : "fr_TD"
  - 776 : "zh_Hans_HK"
  - 777 : "is"
  - 778 : "ksh"
  - 779 : "my"
  - 780 : "mn_MN"
  - 781 : "en"
  - 782 : "it"
  - 783 : "dsb_DE"
  - 784 : "ii_CN"
  - 785 : "eo"
  - 786 : "iu"
  - 787 : "en_ZA"
  - 788 : "smn"
  - 789 : "en_AD"
  - 790 : "ak"
  - 791 : "en_RU"
  - 792 : "kkj_CM"
  - 793 : "am"
  - 794 : "es"
  - 795 : "et"
  - 796 : "uk_UA"
```

...