# Using lowercaseString in Swift with the "İ" character

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsstring

In my app, I use `lowercaseString`. When I change "İ" to lowercase, the output is incorrect. It puts more points on the smaller letters:

```
let isim = "titTTSSİŞÇÖÜİİİle".lowercaseString
```

The output is:

`titttssi̇şçöüi̇i̇i̇le`

The correct output for `İ` should be `i`

Comment: Can you post the output as text instead of an image?

Comment: Similar problem for conversion to upper case: [Uppercase All String According to Locale - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715323/uppercase-all-string-according-to-locale-swift)

Comment: The `i̇` is actually the standard lowercase letter `i` and a "combining dot above".

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this is Turkish text. You can use [`lowercaseStringWithLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lowercaseStringWithLocale:) to handle this correctly:

```
4> let isim = "titTTSSİŞÇÖÜİİİle".lowercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "tr"))
isim: String = "titttssişçöüiiile"
```

You may wish to use [`NSLocale.currentLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale) instead, to accommodate users in different locales based on their preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change that character separately. Perhaps something like this:

```
var isim: NSString = "titTTSSİŞÇÖÜİİİle".lowercaseString
isim = isim.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("İ", withString: "i")
```

Hope this helps.