# How to uppercase Turkish "i"?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, turkish

In Turkish, there are two ***i***

- Dotless: ***ı***, ***I***
- Dotted: ***i***, ***İ***

**PROBLEM:** Every time I uppercase an ***i***, I get an ***I***.

I want to get an ***İ*** (only in Turkish) when I uppercase an ***i***, and an ***I*** when I uppercase an ***ı***.

I have a function to do it

```
@objc public static func uppercaseTurkishString(_ string: String) -> String {
    return String(string.map { (char) -> Character in
        if char == "i" {
            return "İ"
        } else {
            return Character(String(char).uppercased())
        }
    })
}
```

But I have to check if the language is Turkish every time I use it, and doing it for every single string in the app is a very hard job.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: There is a strange difference, if you do `let turckishI = "Dotless: ı, I Dotted: i, İ"`, then `turckishI.localizedLowercase`, you'll see that the rendered lowercase i (the last one) is different from yours. But there is also locale uppercase.

Comment: Related: [Uppercase All String According to Locale - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715323/uppercase-all-string-according-to-locale-swift)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that the `uppercased()` function doesn't care about `Locale`s and the small dotted *i* looks like the normal English *i*. You should use `localizedUppercase`, which will use the Turkish `Locale` for Turkish users (or `uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr_TR")`, in case you want this to be done for all users of your app regardless of their locale settings, but I wouldn't recommend that).

Moreover, there's no need to do the upper casing character-by-character, you can simply do it on the full `String`.

```
@objc public static func uppercaseTurkishString(_ string: String) -> String {
    return string.localizedUppercase
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Foundation` developers already thought about it, and that's exactly why there is [`uppercased(with: Locale?)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413316-uppercased):

```
"i".uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr_TR")) // returns "İ"
"i".uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "en_US")) // returns "I"
"ı".uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr_TR")) // returns "I"
```